# Alternative for isToken() method of Struts in Spring

Tags: java, spring, struts

Do we have any alternative for `isToken()` method of Struts in Spring? I am facing an issue when a user performs save operation. The value is saved, but if he clicks on refresh button in the browser it takes the old value and again populates the same value in database.